# ManyToMany as Inline

Tags: django, django-admin

When trying to use a ManyToMany relation as an Inline in a ModelAdmin, cause the error admin.E105 at the bottom, but under normal circunstances, without inline, it works fine. Here is the code:

**models.py**

```
class Reference(models.Model):
    url = models.UrlField()
    ...


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    ...
    references = models.ManyToManyField(
            Reference,
            related_name="references_%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
        )

    class Meta:
        abstract=True


class Case(BaseModel)
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class InlineReference(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BaseModel.references.through


class CaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [InlineReference, ]
    exclude = ['references', ]
    ...
```

The error message is:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
<class 'admin.CaseAdmin'>: (admin.E105) 'admin.InlineReference' must have a 'model' attribute.
```

I'm trying to follow the docs from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Answer (score -1):

You must set model attribute Reference model.

```
class InlineReference(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Reference


class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [InlineReference, ]
    ...

admin.site.register(Base, BaseAdmin)
```

Comment: I did that, but does not work, because is a ManyToMany relation. The error in that case mentions that there is no Foreignkey relation between Case and Reference, something like that.

Comment: Maybe you did not do migrate act